# Does a work of art contain any meaning one can come up with?

Tags: aesthetics, art, interpretation

I've read in some blog that any piece of art contains any meaning that any reader or spectator may find in it.

Has something similar been explored in philosophical works, or was it an 'original' opinion of the author?

Comment: Sounds like reader response theory.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There was a story in the UK newspapers not long ago, where a young student had to do a book report analysing the meaning of a book, he knew the author personally and asked him, and he got a "D" for his efforts, being told by the teacher that he completely misunderstood the book.

Comment: This does not answer your question but gives you some small idea of what is available. https://www.iep.utm.edu/aestheti/

Comment: If you are in college or even just near a university library or other good library, I hope you will explore this yourself. In the Philosophy section (philosophy of art etc), Art section, aesthetics, also in Literature. Yes there is something in philosophy for you on the subject and the books are lonely just waiting for you, even Derrida.

Comment: I just noticed that the IEP link above may indeed help with your question or get you started see sec. 5 intentions.